Get Firefox's iOS app to show tabs in two columns
I use the "Larger Text" Display Zoom option. Until recently, when I switched between tabs in the Firefox iOS app, it would show the open tabs arranged in two columns. But recently, the Firefox app has begun showing my open tabs arranged in a single column, with the preview of each open tab so large that it takes up almost the whole iPhone screen, so I can now only preview one tab at a time. This basically defeats the purpose of previewing all the open tabs in the tab switching screen.
How can I get Firefox's tab switching screen to display my open tabs arranged in two columns again, rather than one?
